# Re-usable HTML code / widgets

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

Sometimes I need to use the same html code in different templates, like:

```
<div class="mylist"><span>item-1</span><span>item-2</span>...</div>
```

or more complicated widgets. I'm new to Django so I want to learn what do you usually do in these kinds of situations? Do you create your own template tags or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're after an inclusion tag, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags .

An inclusion tag is a very simple type of template tag for breaking out markup and code into other templates.  This should fit the bill for your example.

You can write more complicated template tags to do pretty much anything else you need if you need to eventually, but inclusion tags are a good place to start.